# nv.d3 lineplusbarchart x-axis date value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I have gating problems for set date on x-axis in lineplusbarchart.Its showing all dates 01/01/70 and yaxis data showing as i need.

Please help me to solve this out.

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart();        
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    $('#dp2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $("#chart svg").html('');
        drawgraph();
    });

    $('#dp1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $("#chart svg").html('');
        drawgraph();
    });

    var drawgraph = function () {
        var startDate = $("#dp2 input").val();
        var endDate = $("#dp1 input").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ("Default.aspx/GetData"),
            data: "{startDate:'" + startDate + "',endDate:'" + endDate + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                var data = $.parseJSON(result.d);


                var series = [data].map(function (series) {
                    series.values = series.values.map(function (data) { return { x: data[0], y: data[1]} });
                    return series;
                });

                nv.addGraph(function () {

                    chart.margin({ top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70 });

                    chart.color(d3.scale.category10().range());

                    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (data) {

                        var dx = series[0].values[data] && series[0].values[data].x || 0;                            
                        // return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))

                        return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(dx));
                    });

                    chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
                    chart.bars.forceY([0]);


                    d3.select("#chart svg")
                                 .datum(series)
                                 .transition().duration(1200)
                                 .call(chart);

                    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                    return chart;

                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, txt, err) {
                alert("error connecting to data: " + txt);
            }

        });

    }
    window.onload = drawgraph;

</script>
```

and for .cs page code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    end.Value = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    start.Value = date.Date.AddDays(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public static string GetData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("TotalCalls_Dashboard", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
               sda.Fill(ds);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();                   
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();                  

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                        Int64[] temp2 = new Int64[2];                         

                        DateTime test = new DateTime();
                        test = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CallDate"].ToString());

                        var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, test.Kind);
                        var unixTimestamp = System.Convert.ToInt64((test - date).TotalSeconds);

                        temp2[0] = Convert.ToInt64(unixTimestamp);
                        temp2[1] = Int64.Parse(dr["AnsweredCall"].ToString());                                                
                        al.Add(temp2);

                   }

                Stats stat = new Stats();
                stat.key = "AnsweredCall";
                stat.bar = true;
                stat.values = al;                    

                return serializer.Serialize(stat);                         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

public class Stats
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public bool bar { get; set; }
    public ArrayList values { get; set; }
}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the dates, i.e.

```
series.values = series.values.map(function (data) { return { x: data[0], y: data[1]} });
```

should be

```
series.values = series.values.map(function (data) { return { x: d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse(data[0]), y: data[1]} });
```

based on your other code. You may have to adjust the format string if your date format is different.

Then you shouldn't need the `chart.xAxis.tickFormat` definition anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But i still get error when i follow your code then string.substring is not a function.Please suggest what i do further.

Comment: Could you post a complete working example (JS code only, preferably on something like jsfiddle) that demonstrates the problem please?